# libseccomp seems to be not working as expected

Tags: security

```
int python_seccomp_rules(struct config *_config)
{
   // Syscalls blacklist array
    int syscalls_blacklist[] = {
        SCMP_SYS(fork), SCMP_SYS(vfork), SCMP_SYS(kill)
    };

    // Initializing seccomp context
    scmp_filter_ctx ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_ALLOW);
    if (!ctx)
    {
        return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
    }

    // Blacklist specified syscalls
    int syscalls_blacklist_length = sizeof(syscalls_blacklist) / sizeof(int);
    for (int i = 0; i < syscalls_blacklist_length; i++)
    {
        if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_KILL, syscalls_blacklist[i], 0) != 0)
        {
            seccomp_release(ctx);
            return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
        }
    }
    
    // load seccomp into the kernel
```

When I traced it using strace command, I got the following output:

```
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_STRICT, 0x1, NULL) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER, SECCOMP_FILTER_FLAG_TSYNC, NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER, SECCOMP_FILTER_FLAG_LOG, NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_GET_ACTION_AVAIL, 0, [SECCOMP_RET_LOG]) = 0
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_GET_ACTION_AVAIL, 0, [SECCOMP_RET_KILL_PROCESS]) = 0
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER, SECCOMP_FILTER_FLAG_SPEC_ALLOW, NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER, SECCOMP_FILTER_FLAG_NEW_LISTENER, NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_GET_NOTIF_SIZES, 0, {seccomp_notif=80, seccomp_notif_resp=24, seccomp_data=64}) = 0
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER, SECCOMP_FILTER_FLAG_TSYNC_ESRCH, NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
6885  15:57:14 prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1, 0, 0, 0) = 0
6885  15:57:14 seccomp(SECCOMP_SET_MODE_FILTER, 0, {len=30, filter=0x55a7aaa8b490}) = 0
```

Comment: Details in the title may **not** be readable on all devices when reading your question; there is no actual question currently, nor any OS/release detail mentioned & thus nothing currently on-topic for this site.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic and amend your question to make it clear & on-topic (*assuming it is on-topic; I currently see no connection as you appear to pasting programming details & haven't yet asked your question just made a statement about what you see with `strace` for an unstated OS*).